# Create a new file by removing the new line character at the end of file

Tags: shell-script, ksh

I have a flat file which contains the following data records between H: and T:.

```
H:20050427 HEADER RECORD
0000000 00000 000000000 123456 00 654321 DATARECORD
0000000 00000 000000000 123456 00 654321 DATARECORD
0000000 00000 000000000 123456 00 654321 DATARECORD
0000000 00000 000000000 123456 00 654321 DATARECORD
T:20050427 TRAILER RECORD
[blank space]
```

[blank space] is a new line (carriage return key) created with no records after T:

How do I remove the blank space(s) (if present) from the file and create a new file with data which are present between H: and T:?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to remove **all** `[blank space]` (may contain any whitespace in general) lines:

```
sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/ d' filename > newfile
```

or simply (why bother with `awk` or `sed`):

```
grep . filename > newfile
```

or to print only between H: and T: lines:

```
sed -n '/^H:.*/, /^T:.*/ p' filename > newfile
```

Answer (score 0):

You're kind of asking two different questions; I'm not sure which you're actually trying to do

#### Remove blank lines

Use `awk` to match any line with a character on it and only output those:

```
$ awk '/./ {print}' /path/to/your/file
```

#### Only output lines between H: and T:

Use `awk` to match the lines that start with `H:` and `T:` and only output the lines between them (this assumes none of the other lines will have those prefixes):

```
$ awk '/^H:/,/^T:/ {print}' /path/to/your/file
```